# Jquery hide multiple divs onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am making a fitness application, on each exercise page I have a buttons which display the 'information','data input' and the'progress'. This is working fine, however, when the buttons are clicked the divs layer over the top each other and displayed at the same time.

What I want is the information to primarily be displayed but when the user clicks the other buttons the other button divs are hidden. Thus only displaying one div at a time.

HTML

```
<div id="buttons">
    <a class="Smallbutton" id="showInfo">
        <img src="img/info.png" />
    </a>
    <a class="Smallbutton" id="showDataInput">
        <img src="img/add-item.png" />
    </a>
    <a class="Smallbutton" id="showHistory">
        <img src="img/bar-chart.png" />
    </a>
</div>
<div class="info" style="display: none;">
    <p>Position yourself on the edge of the chair and grab hold of the seat just under your legs. Do the crunches by lifting
        yourself from the seat and bring the knees to your chest.</p>
</div>
<div class="dataInput" style="display: none;">
    <form onsubmit="save_data()">
        Reps:
        <input id="reps" type="number" name="quantity" min="1" max="12" step="1" required>Sets:
        <input id="sets" type="number" name="quantity" min="1" max="4" step="1" required>
        <input type="submit" value="Add Log" onclick="insert(this.form.reps.value,this.form.sets.value);show();">
</div>
<div class="history" style="display: none;">
    <div id="log"></div>
    <!--clears all data in localstorage-->
    <input type="button" value="Clear" onclick="clearLocal();" />
</div>
```

SCRIPT

```
//JQUERY SHOW/HIDE HISTORY

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#showHistory').click(function() {
            $('.history').slideToggle("fast");
    });
});



//JQUERY SHOW/HIDE DATA INPUT

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#showDataInput').click(function() {
            $('.dataInput').slideToggle("fast");

    });
});

//JQUERY SHOW/HIDE INFO

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#showInfo').click(function() {
            $('.info').slideToggle("fast");

    });
});
```

Here is my JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/GYru6/

Thank you in advance

I found this example of something that i am after http://jsfiddle.net/XwN2L/ however when i implement the code into my site all the divs are displayed at once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some minor tweaks

- Add a `data-target=""` to all buttons
- Add a class `target` to all the div's

Try

```
<div id="buttons">  
    <a class="Smallbutton" id="showInfo" data-target=".info"><img src="img/info.png"/></a>
    <a class="Smallbutton" id="showDataInput" data-target=".dataInput"><img src="img/add-item.png"/></a>
    <a class="Smallbutton" id="showHistory" data-target=".history"><img src="img/bar-chart.png"/></a>
</div>  

<div class="info target" style="display: none;">
    <p>Position yourself on the edge of the chair and grab hold of the seat just under your legs. Do the crunches by lifting yourself from the seat and bring the knees to your chest.</p>
</div>
<div class="dataInput target" style="display: none;">
    <form onsubmit="save_data()">
        Reps: <input id="reps" type="number" name="quantity" min="1" max="12" step="1" required />
        Sets: <input id="sets" type="number" name="quantity" min="1" max="4" step="1" required />
        <input type="submit" value="Add Log" onclick="insert(this.form.reps.value,this.form.sets.value);show();" />
    </form>
</div>
<div class="history target" style="display: none;">
    <div id="log"></div>
    <!--clears all data in localstorage-->
    <input type="button" value="Clear" onclick="clearLocal();"/>
</div>
```

then

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var $targets = $('.target');
    $('#buttons .Smallbutton').click(function () {
        var $target = $($(this).data('target')).slideToggle();
        $targets.not($target).hide()
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/mdKU4/)

Answer (score 0):

try adding `.hide()` other divs on click function

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#showHistory').click(function() {
            $('.history').slideToggle("fast");
            $('.dataInput').hide(); //hide other elements
            $('.info').hide();  //hide other elements
        });
    });
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/yashhy/nHL4F/)

Answer (score 0):

I would use a hideAll function and call it on each element. this will simplify the logic a bit.

```
function hideAll(){
    $('.info, .dataInput, .history').slideUp();
}
```

and then call it in each of your click events

```
$('#showInfo').click(function() {
    hideAll();
    $('.info').slideToggle("fast");
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/GYru6/1/

Answer (score 0):

Try this way,

The HTML,

```
<div id="buttons">
    <a class="Smallbutton" id="showInfo">
        <img src="img/info.png" />
    </a>
    <a class="Smallbutton" id="showDataInput">
        <img src="img/add-item.png" />
    </a>
    <a class="Smallbutton" id="showHistory">
        <img src="img/bar-chart.png" />
    </a>
</div>
<div class="info infoContainers" style="display: none;">
    <p>Position yourself on the edge of the chair and grab hold of the seat just under your legs. Do the crunches by lifting
        yourself from the seat and bring the knees to your chest.</p>
</div>
<div class="dataInput infoContainers" style="display: none;">
    <form onsubmit="save_data()">
        Reps:
        <input id="reps" type="number" name="quantity" min="1" max="12" step="1" required>Sets:
        <input id="sets" type="number" name="quantity" min="1" max="4" step="1" required>
        <input type="submit" value="Add Log" onclick="insert(this.form.reps.value,this.form.sets.value);show();">
</div>
<div class="history infoContainers" style="display: none;">
    <div id="log"></div>
    <!--clears all data in localstorage-->
    <input type="button" value="Clear" onclick="clearLocal();" />
</div>
```

And the Javascript,

```
//JQUERY SHOW/HIDE HISTORY
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#showHistory').click(function() {
        $('.infoContainers').slideUp();
        $('.history').slideToggle("fast");
    });
});

//JQUERY SHOW/HIDE DATA INPUT
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#showDataInput').click(function() {
        $('.infoContainers').slideUp();
        $('.dataInput').slideToggle("fast");

    });
});

//JQUERY SHOW/HIDE INFO
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#showInfo').click(function() {
        $('.infoContainers').slideUp();
        $('.info').slideToggle("fast");

    });
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/GjLQB/1/)