# jQuery remove added class to all elements after not being used anymore

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to remove added class from sibling elements after function is not used anyomore, but without success.

I use a few lines script from Arun P Johny (found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21726701/jquery-hide-multiple-divs-onclick) with fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/mdKU4/)) and with one added code line that toggles, adds and removes classes, script does the following:

- on click each link/tab (.link) show/hide its own div (.div). (All .divs are initially hidden.)
- when second .link is clicked while the first one is active (has visible .div), the visible .div hides and the other one shows
- clicked .link gets class .selected, while others get class .not-selected, so I can target them while at least one link is active (shows .div)
- when .link is clicked again (and .div hides), class .selected is removed

Here is the code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var $targets = $(".div");
    $(".link").click(function () {
        var $target = $($(this).data("target")).fadeToggle("slow");
        $targets.not($target).hide();
        $(this).toggleClass("selected").removeClass("not-selected").siblings().addClass("not-selected").removeClass("selected");
    });
});
```

What I cannot make it work is when .link is clicked again (and .div hides), I cannot remove .not-selected class from all other (sibling) .links. When no .div is visible, I want that links do not have class .not-selected, just like they didn't have it before the first .link was clicked.

To visualize: imagine .links are tabs with background color gray. When I click on each tab it becomes yellow (and opens some content), while others become blue. But when I click yellow tab again and content hides, I want all tabs to become gray again (lose blue color).

If I change addClass to toggleClass:

```
(...).siblings().toggleClass("not-selected").(...)
```

it doesn't do the trick completely. It works if I click twice on the same link/tab, but when I click one tab after another it still removes .not-selected class, but it shouldn't. I tried

```
if ($(".div").not(":visible)) {$(".link").removeClass("not-selected");}
```

but that also does not work, even with .lenght === 0. It removes all .not-selected classes whole time, even when one link/tab is selected.

Help? :-)

Comment: when `toggleClass` does not work expectedly, the elements might have wrong ***initial*** class, so toggling just makes chaining wrong result. to force the toggling-off, you can try `.toggleClass("not-selected", false)`. By the way, you don't need 2 separate classes for 1 meaning (selected or not). Just one class of `selected` is enough. Removing that class means the element is not selected.

Comment: It's true that if I set class '.selected' to one link, it means that all other links are not selected. However, I want to target (with CSS) not selected links ONLY when one link is selected. Not before, and not after. From the example above, how can I color gray sibling tabs blue, only while $this tab is clicked (and showing some content in .div)? I think only dynamicaly with jQuery. But the problem is that when I hide .div (by clicking yellow tab again) sibling tabs stay blue (because class '.not-selected' is not removed).

Comment: to target elements which do not have a class, use `:not`. For e.g: `div:not(.selected)`

Comment: Let me try to explain it this way. .links can have state "initial" and "active". "Initial" state is when the page is loaded and all .divs are hidden. When you click on the .link, function is called which shows the .div and links are in the state of "active". When the same .link is clicked again, .div is hidden and .links are back to the "initial" state. I want to change the color of sibling (not clicked) links ONLY when .links are in "active" state. Not before and not after. `a:not(.selected)` will change the color of not selected links in "initial" state as well.